# How to calculate check practically POWER of SMPS required for desktop computer

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, watts, power-consumption

How to calculate check practically POWER of SMPS required for desktop computers

I have  10 desktop pc in one PC i have a high end gaming  gigabyte motherboard with AMD processor graphic card and cooler master  premium extreme cabinet with 5 big cooling fans. I have  600w corsiar true power smps installed in it but still fans and PC works slow

In other desktop PC  I have another medium end gigabyte  motherboard with  normal cabinet with 1 cabinet normal small fan and have 450w normal zebronics smps

Both PC was lagging and slow   and 450wat smps was overheating and just shorted or blasted  then I changed it with corsair true power 600watts smps in medium end desktop pc and founded drastic change in speed of PC with no HDD or other lagging problems and speed and performance was great and I  came to know the difference and need of smps true power

So I decided to purchase true power smps for all my desktop machines but all of them have different boards low level medium and high level

Now my question is that

1. As motherboards ram hdd graphic cards cpu cabinets fans dont specify the power they need to operate in.
2. How can I monitor or check through software app or device that how much  watts will they required for optimum performance
3. As in market 450 550 600 800 1000 watts smps  are available which one will be good which pc
4. Is there any reading available in BIOS windows of any power consumption
5. If I give more wattage to lower end  will it damage the board or components
6. Many companies write 600 880 watts how to check before purchasing if they are true power or nor

Waiting for precious and professional advice suggestions and thanks a lot in advance for your help and advice in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking this. The major power consumers in the PC are processor and the video cards. Add those, add 30% overhead, round up and get that power supply.